# How To Check 5 Empty Variables in PHP

Tags: php, conditional-statements, is-empty

I need to make a conditional statement where the 5 variables should be empty before perform an action. The problem is some variables can be zero, false or NULL value. How to catch all of them?

Which one is better?

```
If (!$a && !$b && !$c && !$d && !$e) {

  // do some action 

} else {

  exit;

}
```

OR

```
If (empty($a) && empty($b) && empty($c) && empty($d) && empty($e)) {

  // do some action 

} else {

  exit;

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should first define to yourself exactly what 'empty' means.

Comment: Using `empty` means you won't get any errors if the variables don't exist, but otherwise these are equivalent. Use whichever makes you feel warm and fuzzy inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be an approach to check multiple variables are **empty** at once.

```
<?php
$a = $b = $c = $d = $e = '';
#$b = 5; // comment out to go on else block
if (empty($a . $b . $c . $d . $e)){
    echo "All variables are empty, do what you want to do man";
}else{
    echo "One of variable is not empty";
}
?>
```

Comment: This is a good approach I looking for. I marked your answer as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @DrunkenM glad it helps you somehow, best of luck

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use "code sample" to show code.

When you use `!$a` you are actually casting **$a** to boolean.
The problem here is

```
$a = 0;
if (!$a) {
  echo 'NOT EMPTY';
} else {
   echo 'EMPTY';
}
//OUTPUT EMPTY BECAUSE 0 to boolean is FALSE
```

Same example with **NULL** value.

About **empty** i advice you to check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues)

Read it and choose the way that fit your needs.

Hope this helps